# how to cycle these values with javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

how to cycle below values with javascript?

```
0, -120, -240, -360, -480, -600, -720
```

to get the output like

```
0 -120 -240 -360 -480 -600 -720 0 -120 -240 -360 -480 -600 -720 0 -120 -240 -360 -480 -600 -720 .....
```

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "cycle"? do you want to loop it?

Comment: yeah loop in a cycle start from 0 and end with -720 then start from 0 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `for` loops:

```
var cycles = 10;
var numbers = [0, -120, -240, -360, -480, -600, -720];
for (var i = 0; i < cycles; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        // concatenate here
    }
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jXxwu/).

Comment: `while (cycles--) { ... }` is a good way to do count downs =)

Comment: thanks any idea how to delay showing numbers inside for loop?

Answer (score 1):

What about this,

```
var cycles = 10;
var current_cycle = 0
var numbers = [0, -120, -240, -360, -480, -600, -720];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    document.write( numbers[i] )
    if( (i+1) == numbers.length ){ // last item in the current cycle
        current_cycle++;
        if(current_cycle < cycles){
            i = 0; // re-starts the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
var d = -120, n = 7, s = 0, c = n * 2, limit = d * n;
var result = []
while (c--) {
  result.push(s % limit);  
  s += d;
}
alert(result); // 0,-120,-240,-360,-480,-600,-720,0,-120,-240,-360,-480,-600,-720
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [0, -120, -240, -360, -480, -600, -720];
var count = 3;
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   output = output.concat(arr);
}
alert(output);
```

[working code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/A4DHn/)